# Putting the text after the line legend

Tags: plotting, legending, labeling

I want to put the line legend after the text, 
here is my code;

```
tn = .005;
lg = LineLegend[{Directive[Thick, Line, Black], 
   Directive[Thick, Black, Dashed], Directive[Thick, Red, Line], 
   Directive[Thick, Red, Dashed], 
   Directive[Thickness[tn], Line, Blue]}, {"Forward Pump", 
   "Backward Pump", Style["Forward Signal", Red], 
   Style["Backward Signal", Red], Style["ΔT", Blue]}, 
  Spacings -> {.1, 2}, LegendMarkerSize -> 50, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, 15], LegendLayout -> "Row"]
```

The output is[image]

I want to make it like the following image,

[image: The text should be before the line legend]

Could you please let me know how I can put the text before the line legend?

Answer (score 7):

Create your own layout function. For example:

```
myLayout[pairs_] := Grid[
    Partition[
        myRow /@ pairs,
        UpTo[3]
    ],
    Alignment -> Left
]

myRow[{legend_, label_}] := Row[{label, " ", legend}]
```

Then:

```
tn = .005;
lg = LineLegend[
    {Directive[Thick,Line,Black], Directive[Thick,Black,Dashed],Directive[Thick,Red,Line],Directive[Thick,Red,Dashed],Directive[Thickness[tn],Line,Blue]},
    {"Forward Pump","Backward Pump",Style["Forward Signal",Red],Style["Backward Signal",Red],Style["ΔT",Blue]},
    Spacings->{.1,2},
    LegendMarkerSize->50,
    LabelStyle->Directive[Bold,15],
    LegendLayout->myLayout
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

#### "MarkerLayout"

There is an (undocumented) option `"MarkerLayout"` to directly control the position of legend markers with respect to labels.

The usage is `"MarkerLayout" -> pos` where `pos` can be any of symbolic positions `"Above"`,`"Below"`, `"Before"` and `"After"` (or `Above`, `Below`, `Before` and `After`).

So, you can add the option  `"MarkerLayout" -> "After"` to get the desired result:

```
directives = {Directive[Thick, Line, Black], Directive[Thick, Black, Dashed], 
  Directive[Thick, Red, Line], Directive[Thick, Red, Dashed], 
  Directive[Thickness[tn], Line, Blue]}; 

labels = {"Forward Pump", "Backward Pump", Style["Forward Signal", Red], 
  Style["Backward Signal", Red], Style["ΔT", Blue]};

LineLegend[directives, labels, Spacings -> {.1, 2}, LegendMarkerSize -> 50, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, 15], LegendLayout -> "Row", 
 "MarkerLayout" -> "After"]
```

[image]

```
LineLegend[directives, labels, Spacings -> 2, 
 LegendMarkerSize -> {50, 10}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, 15], 
 LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}, "MarkerLayout" -> "Above"]
```

[image]

Use `"MarkerLayout" -> "Below"` to get

[image]

The same option also works with `SwatchLegend` and `PointLegend`:

```
Row[SwatchLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, {"red", "green", "blue"}, 
    LegendLayout -> "Column", "MarkerLayout" -> #] & /@ 
 {Before, After, Above, Below}, Spacer[20]]
```

[image]

Replace `LegendLayout -> "Column"` with `LegendLayout -> "Row"` to get

[image]

```
Row[PointLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, {"red", "green", "blue"}, 
    LegendLayout -> "Column", Method -> "MarkerLayout" -> #] & /@
  {Before, After, Above, Below}, Spacer[20]]
```

[image]

Replace `LegendLayout -> "Column"` with `LegendLayout -> "Row"` to get

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use the option `LegendFunction` with a custom function that reverses the ordering of labels and markers:

```
ClearAll[legendFunction]
legendFunction = Replace[#, 
           a : {PatternSequence[_Graphics, _] ..} :> 
                BlockMap[Apply[Sequence] @* Reverse, a, 2], 
     All] &;
```

**Examples:**

```
LineLegend[{Directive[Thick, Line, Black], 
    Directive[Thick, Black, Dashed], Directive[Thick, Red, Line], 
    Directive[Thick, Red, Dashed], 
    Directive[Thickness[tn], Line, Blue]}, {"Forward Pump", 
    "Backward Pump", Style["Forward Signal", Red], 
    Style["Backward Signal", Red], Style["ΔT", Blue]}, 
  Spacings -> {.1, 2}, LegendMarkerSize -> 50, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, 15], LegendLayout -> "Row", 
  LegendFunction -> (Framed[legendFunction @ #] &)]
```

[image]

With  `Spacings -> {.5, 0, 3}`,  `LegendLayout -> {"ReversedColumn", 2}` and
 `LegendFunction ->(Panel[legendFunction@#,  Background -> LightBlue]&)` we get:

[image]