# How to put the text after the point legend?

Tags: plotting, functions, legending

Last time I asked a question about putting the text after the line legend [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/270106/how-can-i-flip-mirror-the-legend) and it works fine for that example.

[image]

```
LineLegend[{Red, Blue}, {"cubic", "quadratic"}, 
 LegendLayout -> "Column", "MarkerLayout" -> After]
```

Now I also want to apply this to this PointLegend by adding `Method->"MarkerLayout" -> After` mentioned by kglr [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/236636/82512) but it doesn't work. How can I fix this?

```
ClearAll[legend1]
Options[legend1] = {Joined -> Automatic};
legend1[colors_, polymarkers_, legend__, , OptionsPattern[]] := 
 PointLegend[colors, legend, Joined -> OptionValue[Joined], 
  LegendMarkers -> (ResourceFunction["PolygonMarker"][#, Offset[4], 
       EdgeForm[]] & /@ polymarkers), LegendMarkerSize -> {30, 30}, 
  LegendLayout -> (Column[
      Grid[{##}, Alignment -> {Center, Center}] & /@ #, 
      Spacings -> -1] &), Method->"MarkerLayout" -> After]
colors = ColorData[97, #] & /@ Range[6];
polymarkers = {"DownTriangle", "SevenPointedStar", "FourPointedStar", 
   "Diamond"};
mylegend = 
  MaTeX[TeXForm[#], Magnification -> 0.5] & /@ {{"5X", "6Y", "8Z", 
     "9M", "2K", "2N", "2T", "3N", "5O"}, {"1X", "3Y", "5Z", "2L", 
     "9K", "3Z", "7X", "3P", "2T"}, {"3K", "6M"}, {"3H", "6K"}, {"X4",
      "Y5", "C6", "1K"}, {"X6", "Y6", "C6", "Z6"}};
legend1[colors, polymarkers, mylegend, , Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

`Method` is overrided because you specified `LegendLayout`. The solution is to manually set a "reversed" `LegendLayout`:

```
LegendLayout -> (Grid[Reverse /@ #, Alignment -> {Right, Center}, Spacings -> {1, -1}] &)
```

[image]